# Github, binding an issue to another issue to trigger next issue movement to a column

Tags: events, github, tree, issue-tracking

How can I bind an issue to another issue, such that it will trigger the other issue to do something?

[image]

In the upper example, when "explicit device" issue is moved to "finished" column, I want the "error handling"(leftmost) issue to move to "in progress" column automatically. Because I may not remember which needs what and what was which, needing to check all issues whenever an issue is finished and would become tiring after some point.

---

Even better, building an issue tree, finishing from ground up without stopping by all issues for just finding the closest root of an issue, isn't an option?

---

Another example:

- add method is written: "issue1" complete
- multiply method is written: "issue2" complete
- suddenly, a multiply-add method as "issue3" pops in the beginning column or if it is already there, it moves to right by 1 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of [project board](https://help.github.com/articles/tracking-the-progress-of-your-work-with-project-boards/) presented in [GitHub Universe 2016](https://github.com/blog/2256-a-whole-new-github-universe-announcing-new-tools-forums-and-features) is still lacking in term of fine-grained issue management.

That is why you have so [many third-party integrations](https://github.com/integrations/feature/project-management), including **[ZenHub](https://www.zenhub.com/)** (free for small teams and public account), which does have more features.
The point is: look for third-party integration (with a free offer) for your feature.

Comment: Epic issue in zenhub seems to be what I need. Thank you